# Найти INT_MIN, INT_MAX без заголовочных файлов

Tags: c

Как найти значения `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX` переносимым способом, без использования заголовочных файлов, чтобы работало на машинах с дополнением до двойки и до единицы?

Comment: Наверное достаточно узнать sizeof(int), а потом загнать в старший бит 1 (получим INT_MIN), ну а ~INT_MIN будет INT_MAX-ом

Comment: Пардон, **не прочел самое главное ограничение** (дополнение до 1, т.е. инверсный код). Понятно, что предложенный способ (1 в старшем бите) работает с дополнение до 2 (а с другой стороны, где вы сейчас найдете такой комп?)

Comment: А зачем? Чем хедер не переносим?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, чтобы лучше знать язык.

Comment: Теоретический вопрос: может ли количество бит/байт в `type` и `unsigned type` быть разным?...

Comment: Если количество padding bits в типах `int` и `unsigned int` одинаково, то `INT_MAX` равен `(int)((unsigned int)-1 >> 1)`, а `INT_MIN` равен `-INT_MAX - ((-1 & 3) == 3)`. Это должно работать в прямом, обратном и дополнительном кодах.

Comment: Размеры в байтах некоторого целочисленного знакового типа и соответствующего ему беззнакового типа равны. Но не все биты типа обязаны участвовать в кодировании целочисленного значения. Биты в целочисленном типе делятся на три группы: value bits, sign bit и padding bits. Стандарт гарантирует, что количество value bits в знаковом типе (`M`) не превосходит количества value bits в соответствующем беззнаковом типе (`N`): `M <= N`. Но не гарантирует удобного соотношения `M == N-1`.

Comment: Поэтому возможны экзотические варианты. Например `32`-битный `unsigned int` с `32` value bits и `32`-битный `int` с `25` value bits, `1` sign bit и `6` padding bits. В такой странной реализации предложенный мной вариант не годится, т.к. результат выражения `(unsigned int)-1 >> 1` не представим типом `int`, и попытка привести этот результат к типу `int` сгенерирует «implementation-defined value or an implementation-defined signal is raised». Всё написанное выше верно для C11. Начиная с C23 экзотический вариант больше невозможен, т.к. гарантируется дополнительный код и равенство `M == N-1`.

Comment: @wololo, оформите ваши комментарии как ответ.

Comment: А пардон, забыл ещё про один момент. В дополнительном коде битовый паттерн `10000....00` не обязательно кодирует минимальное целое. Это ещё может быть и trap representation. Эх, накрылся медным тазом мой вариант вычисления `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @wololo, если исключить trap representation и разнобитицу, ваш вариант рабочий. И никто другой так не разберет все случаи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно заметить, что битовое представление минимального и максимального числа не зависит от того, используется ли дополнение до двойки или до единицы:

- Максимальное: `0111...111`.
- Минимальное: `1000...000`.

Поэтому максимум можно получить как `(int)(~0u >> 1)`, а минимум как `(int)~(~0u >> 1)`.

Comment: Хорошее решение. То что мне нужно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Про удаленный комментарий -  Это уход куда-то сильно глубоко в теорию. Все такие проблемы решаются тестами, и выносом этого хака в какую-то одну функцию/макрос, чтобы если что, поправить только в одном месте. Да и я не думаю, что можно как-то защититься от такого trap representation. (Как узнать, есть он или нет, не напоровшись на него? Только посмотрев на INT_MIN?)

Comment: Я тоже пришел к выводу что с trap representation жизнь не возможна. Если их нет, ваш метод решает. Если они есть, ничего нельзя сделать. Потому и удалил комментарий.